# Set Value to Placeholder option of EntityType in symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony, drop-down-menu, entity

I am a beginner in symfony.
Is there any way to set a value to my placeholder in EntityType of formtype
My current formtype is

```
$builder
    ->add('scheme', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Lottery\Masters\MasterScheme',
        'placeholder' => '-- Select Scheme --',
        'choice_label' => 'schemeName',
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'select'
        )
    )
);
```

And when I inspect my dropdown there is no value for the placeholder `---Select Scheme--` .Is there is any way to give value to my placeholder
Hope i Get a solution

Comment: Are you sure that you want to have value for a placeholder (that sounds somewhat strange concept in general to me)? I.e. you're not after setting a default value from your MasterScheme entity for example? But to answer to your question, you can achieve something like this by removing the placeholder setting and by creating a custom instance of MasterSceheme (either in the fly or in the db level) that you use as default "placeholder" for the dropdown (this ofc will require custom processing/validation to be implemented as well to handle the form submits etc)

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for an empty value? So, it will be popluated as the first thing in the drop down. Then you can like this,

```
$builder->add('name', null, array(
    'required'   => false,
    'empty_data' => 'John Doe',
));
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#empty-data

If you meant the Label (a text next to the drop down), use this

```
$builder->add('users', EntityType::class, array(
    'class' => User::class,
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->orderBy('u.username', 'ASC');
    },
    'choice_label' => 'username',
));
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities

Comment: Nothing Happened..When i trying it.The Placeholder itself is not displaying

Comment: I have slightly changed my answer. Could you please try again. Thank you